# Página de manutenção ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um site ASP.NET MVC que quando entra em manutenção preciso exibir uma pagina de manutenção, o ASP.NET MVC tem alguma possibilidade de fazer isso apenas trocando um chave no `Web.Config` ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução que não é muito elegante mas que resolveu meu problema sem muito complicação.

1º Criei um arquivo index.html que é minha pagina de manutenção contendo o conteúdo que deve ser exibido quando o site estiver fora do ar.

2º Coloquei ele na raiz do meu projeto MVC.

3º Quando preciso colocar o site em manutenção eu renomeio o arquivo Global.asax para outro nome qualquer, tipo: GlobalManutencao.asax.

Eu acredito que automaticamente o IIS deixa de olhar para esse arquivo como principal e passa a olhar para o index.html.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Diretamente, de forma pronta, não dá.

Nada impede de você criar um código que cuide disse e decida se vai atender a requisição feita ou vai mostrar a página de manutenção. E também nada impede de colocar uma configuração em algum lugar que o código leia e determine se deve fazer isso ou não. Existem inúmeras formas de fazer isso.

Não acho o `web.config` adequado, mas pode sr usado. Idealmente deveria haver uma sinalização que o arquivo foi modificado para "virar a chave" dentro da aplicação. Assim evita-se a forma ingênua de olhar como está o arquivo toda requisição que for processada para saber o que fazer.

[Um exemplo de implementação](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/how-to-take-an-asp-net-mvc-web-site-down-for-maintenance/).

[Outra abordagem](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/take-your-asp-net-mvc-application-offline-via-a-global-attribute).

Comment: Eu tinha visto esta primeira abordagem mas não consegui entender muito bem, vou tentar dar uma olhada melhor, achei que fosse mais simples. Vlw

Comment: Existe alguma forma que eu possa fazer isso de uma maneira mais simples?

Comment: O ASP.Net tinha algo pronto bem simples, basta colocar a página na pasta (acho que era `offline.html`) e já funcionava. O MVC te dá liberdade, mas exige que você se vire.

Comment: Bom resolvi de uma forma meia zuada mas simples, renomenando arquivo Global.asax para qualquer coisa para a aplicação parar de funcionar. e adicionei um index.hml na raiz para ele exibir.

Comment: Não deixa de ser uma forma :)